# Does Sonar's complexity metric include equals() and hashCode() methods

Tags: java, sonarqube

When Sonar calculates cyclomatic complexity are the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods included?

If so is there some way to exclude them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every method is used to compute the overall complexity of the enclosing class.

I guess I understand why you're asking such a question: modern IDEs generate the `#equals()` and `#hashCode()` methods for you, and those generated method tend to be quite complex. However, they are completely part of your code, and they truly add complexity: they should be tested - like any other method, to prevent any regression.

Comment: I agree that they should be tested, however I don't necessarily want the complexity to be reported with the rest of the class.